# Pandas: groupby and return mean value of a non-numeric variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to aggregate the mean visits per page made by visitors to a website grouped by their visitor id's and pages they visited.

In the example data below `unique_visit` is the individual visits, `visitor_id` is who visited, and `page` is the page they visited.

I want to compute the following: visitor 009903 visited page 3ghtr three times, page 4ifac once and page 9fgvb once. The mean page visits of visitor 009903 is therefore x. And do this for each visitor.

I'm aiming to return an aggregated DataFrame / Series where column 1 would be the visitor_id and column 2 would be a mean number as an 'int64'.

```
unique_visit   visitor_id   page    time
6789988        009903       4ifac   07:01
1978678        001068       9fgvb   11:04
7179832        001624       3ghtr   21:22
4567891        001068       4ifac   16:57
2374852        009903       3ghtr   14:39
2179435        001624       4ifac   21:02
3449855        009903       3ghtr   13:23
6789870        009903       9fgvb   09:34
3439455        009903       3ghtr   14:51
```

Comment: So you want to count the number of visits (so rows) per visitor_id and per page?

Comment: how is the average for `009903` 3

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the count of the unique page visits by visitor_id

Comment: user 009903 visits page 3ghtr twice so the total is 3 rather than 4

Comment: @EdChum, yep as soon as I commented I saw it, I read the data wrong.

Comment: Sorry, this is really hard to articulate. @PadraicCunningham - that is just a guide, it is not exact.

Comment: @Jonathan,  are we talking about something like grouping by  `df.groupby(("visitor_id", "page"))["page"].count()` and getting the mean from that?

Comment: For example: 009903 visits different pages more than once. What is the mean for his visits to pages.

Comment: he/she visits four times, three of which are unique so how do you get three as the mean?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ignore the 3 thing, I will edit the question. Yes, I want the mean of the `df.groupby(("visitor_id", "page"))["page"].count()` you wrote. But I can do what you have written here. I can't now get the mean by visitor_id if that make sense!

Comment: what should the output be, if you add that to your question it will make it  lot easier to know exactly what you want, if you wanted unique visits you could simply drop dupes based on id and page `df.drop_duplicates(("visitor_id", "page")).groupby(("visitor_id", "page"))`

Comment: I have edited the question - hopefully it is clearer now. Sincere apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first count the number of visits per visitor / per page (with groupby):

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['visitor_id', 'page'])['unique_visit'].count()
Out[11]:
visitor_id  page
1068        4ifac    1
            9fgvb    1
1624        3ghtr    1
            4ifac    1
9903        3ghtr    3
            4ifac    1
            9fgvb    1
Name: unique_visit, dtype: int64
```

From this, you can take the mean for all pages (second level of the index) per visitor:

```
In [13]: df.groupby(['visitor_id', 'page'])['unique_visit'].count().mean(level=0)
Out[13]:
visitor_id
1068    1.000000
1624    1.000000
9903    1.666667
Name: unique_visit, dtype: float64
```